# How to get the actual height of a label with auto-height

Tags: javascript, label, titanium, uilabel, titanium-mobile

I'm aware that this question has appeared in various forms before, but none of the solutions worked out for me...
I'm using the Titanium API 2.1.3, and building for iPhone.

I use a lot of common JS, so I have this:

```
exports.Header = function(title){
var l = Ti.UI.createLabel({
    text: title,
    height: 'auto',
    textAlign: 'left',
    color: '#989898',
    font: {fontSize: exports.defaultFontSize+10, fontFamily: exports.defaultFont, fontWeight: 'bold'}
});
return l;
};
```

And I'm calling the label like so:

```
var qLabel = gui.Header(question);
qLabel.top = 5;
qLabel.left = 10;
qLabel.right = 10;
qLabel.color = "#3B3B3B";
qLabel.font = {fontSize: gui.defaultFontSize+4, fontWeight: 'bold'};
```

I've tried all sorts of things to get the height of the label so far, for instance:

```
qLabel.toImage().height // this returns auto
qLabel.getRect().height // this returns 0
```

and the same thing with getSize().height (this returns 0 as well) or getHeight() (returns auto). I've tried adding it to the parent view first, and then reading the height, but nothing... the last thing I did was this:

```
var qqv = Ti.UI.createView({ width: 'auto', height: 'auto' });

qqv.add(qLabel);
qLabel.show();

Ti.API.info(qLabel.rect.height);
Ti.API.info(qLabel.size.height);
Ti.API.info(qqv.rect.height);
Ti.API.info(qqv.size.height);
```

they all return 0.

I'm getting pretty desperate at this point, and I don't know if this problem is because of the API version I'm using or whatever...any help is appreciated.

**EDIT:**
After some trial and error, I've found that

```
qLabel.toImage().height;
```

returns *some* number, however, it doesn't seem to be the correct height.

Comment: Which platform you are working on? iPhone, iPad or Android?

Comment: I'm working for iPhone. Edited that into the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [postlayout event](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/2.1/index.html#!/api/Titanium.UI.View-event-postlayout)

here is the sample code that will get your label height

```
label.addEventListener('postlayout', function(e) {
    var label_height = e.source.rect.height;
    alert(label_height);
});
```

hope that helped. :)

Comment: It works! Thank you so much. Titatanium can be really weird sometimes.

Comment: if i want to position each one of my element according to previous element i need to use post layout event each time ??

Answer (score 0):

I've ran into the same problem and I didn't want to use a postlayout event on every single element. Instead I used the [size](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI.Label-property-size) property which is a read only and contains the actual sizes of the element. I compared this with the event data from a postlayout event and they gave the exact same values.

So if you want to get the height of an element I suggest you using `$.label1.size.height` instead of adding an event listener all the time. This will also be alot better for the performance of your app because the postlayout event will be fired alot.