# UI element get methods return NAN Titanium

Tags: titanium, titanium-mobile

I have a problem with titanium 3.5.0. When I want to position my ui element based on previous element in the layout with some methods like `getWidth` or `getTop` I'm getting Nan and in the console I'm getting a warning that says:

> Invalid dimension value (nan) requested. Making the dimension undefined instead.

I have `scrollview` and I want to arrange my item into it so what I did
this is my scrollview code

```
var scrollView = Ti.UI.createScrollView({
    contentWidth: 'auto',
    contentHeight: 'auto',
    backgroundColor:'#fff',
    showVerticalScrollIndicator: false,
    showHorizontalScrollIndicator: false,
    height:"100%",
    width: "100%",
    top:36.6
});
```

and the scrollableview code

```
var view = Ti.UI.createView({
      backgroundColor:'#fff',
      borderRadius: 0,
      height: 2000,
      width: Ti.UI.FILL
    });
```

and then I started adding my ui element in the view

```
var type =Ti.UI.createLabel({
    text:"Type",
    color:label_color,
    right:207,
    left:label_p_l,
    font:{ fontFamily: customfont,fontSize:17},
    top:37.5

});   
var p_name=Ti.UI.createLabel({
    text:"Property Name",
    color:label_color,
    left:label_p_l,
    font:{ fontFamily: customfont,fontSize:17},
    top:type.getTop()+label_h+32
});
```

so now it's working perfectly because type has a numeric value and even I added three more element in this way and every things works perfectly after that
I have added the 4th element like this and now when I started to get Nan.

```
var space_Slider = Titanium.UI.createSlider({
         top:space.getTop()+space.getHeight()+15,
         min:0,
         max:1000,
         value:0,
         height:4,
         backgroundColor:"#fff",
         leftTrackImage:'/images/slider_color.png',
         rightTrackImage:'/images/slider_color.png',
         thumbImage:'/images/slider.png',

    });
```

now the `space.getTop()` starts returning Nan

Any ideas how to solve this problem?

Comment: Can you show some code ?

Answer (score 1):

That happens because you've specified width / top not as numeric data type, but as string. `"100%"`, `"15dp"` etc

`getWidth()` returns numeric data types *IFF* you pass numeric to width parameter when constructing the element or invoking setter method.

Furthermore, if you don't specify width / top parameters during construction of the elements they will not return anything.

To get the dimensions of the element you need to add them to some container / parent view  and `postlayout` all elements. After this is done you can ask for dimensions like this:

```
element.size.width
```

Comment: thanks @Funtik bu i did what you said and now i m getting 0 :(

Comment: accoding to this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13012421/how-to-get-the-actual-height-of-a-label-with-auto-height
i can get the value but i need to arrange each item based on the previous item so it will be little wired to use event each time i want to add new item

Comment: you're over complicating  things here. Could you draw the desired layout in some Paint like software and attach it to the question?

Comment: ok but i found some thing that when i use label.getwidth() in a label or textfeild i can get it's value but when i use label.getWidth() inside a slider i get Nan